# Selenium - python - how to find the element at a specific position?

Tags: python, selenium, position

I would like to find the element(s) that exist at a specific position in a Selenium based browser (not necessarily headless). 
I.e., given, a set of coordinates (x, y), I would like to get the list of elements that "live" at that position.

My goal, *in fine* is to automatically detect overlays and modals.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: *Why* do you want to detect this? you can do it, but it isn't simple and will take a long time to execute.

Comment: Hi Guy ! I would like to do it in order to programmatically remove modals when I want to screenshot a web page. Thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do below to get WebElement by coordinates (last child)

```
element = driver.execute_script('return document.elementFromPoint(x, y);')
```

If you need all elements (`element` + all its ancestors up to `html` node):

```
elements = driver.execute_script('return document.elementsFromPoint(x, y);')
```

To pass coordinates to JavaScript from outside:

```
x_coord = 100
y_coord = 150
driver.execute_script('return document.elementsFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);', x_coord, y_coord)
```

Or if you have coordinates as tuple:

```
coords = 100, 150
driver.execute_script('return document.elementsFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1]);', *coords)
```

Comment: You @Andersson are a genius ! Thank you so much for your help !!